How to add verbs using the IISAdministration PowerShell module
Background
I am working on audit and hardening scripts for IIS 10, for CIS benchmarks.  I'm aware that this can be done using the older WebAdministration module or using the appcmd executable, but I am trying to do as much as I can through the IISAdministration module.
The Problem
I'm trying to apply the changes required to meet the CIS Benchmark "4.6 Ensure 'HTTP Trace Method' is disabled". I can get the verbs, I have so far been unabled to Add verbs to the 'requestFiltering'.
I can get the verbs..
$requestConfigSection = Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath 'system.webServer/security/requestFiltering'
$verbsElements = Get-IISConfigElement -ConfigElement $requestConfigSection -ChildElementName 'verbs'

If trace was already present, I could get it like so.
$traceVerb = Get-IISConfigAttributeValue -ConfigElement $verbsElements -AttributeName 'trace'

And set it like this.
Set-IISConfigAttributeValue -ConfigElement $verbsElements -AttributeName 'trace' -AttributeValue $false

How do I add a verb that is not present?
I'm looking for the IISAdministration Module version of this...
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/verbs" -name "." -value @{verb='TRACE';allowed='False'}

Comment Follow-up
I've tried following the .NET method approach, as noted in the comments.  This provided the same results.
(Get-iisserverManager).GetApplicationHostConfiguration().GetSection("system.webServer/security/requestFiltering").GetChildElement('verbs')

I do get a result with with GetCollection(), but not what I would expect.
$requestSection = (Get-iisserverManager).GetApplicationHostConfiguration().GetSection("system.webServer/security/requestFiltering")
$requestSection.GetCollection('verbs')   #empty ConfigurationElement result
$requestSection.GetChildElement('verbs')   #produces the following

Attributes      : {allowUnlisted, applyToWebDAV}
ChildElements   : {}
ElementTagName  : verbs
IsLocallyStored : True
Methods         :
RawAttributes   : {[allowUnlisted, True], [applyToWebDAV, True]}
Schema          : Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElementSchema

To those preferring a full PowerShell result, I am getting the same result using.
$verbsCollection = Get-IISConfigCollection -ConfigElement $requestConfigSection -CollectionName 'verbs'
$verbsCollection.GetType()  # confirms empty colleciton of type ConfigurationElementCollection

It's clearly finding a collection, noted by the absence of any errors, but it's empty.  If I store it to a variable, I can see that it has a type of [ConfigurationElementCollection].  Because it's empty, Get-Member doesn't work, but if I expand $verbsCollection.PSObject.methods I can see that there is an Add() method there.
Why is it empty if GetChildElement product results?
My assumption would be that these are inherited, but this should be pulling from about as high up the hierarchy as I can get.  I can probably find my way from here, but would love an answer to this last question....  and a answer that I can actually mark as an answer.

IISAdministration is there to enable you to write PowerShell in a way more similar to the equivalent C# code with Microsoft.Web.Administration, so if you don't start with Get-IISServerManager https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/get-iisservermanager?view=windowsserver2022-ps you are likely on the wrong path.

Sure...
(Get-iisserverManager).GetApplicationHostConfiguration().GetSection("system.webServer/security/requestFiltering").GetChildElement('verbs')
... but there is still no Add method.


Please edit the question to include new information. Things in comments are just hard to read. 2) With the element at hand, you should call its GetCollection method to access the actual collection of verb items. Then you can find Add method on that collection object. 3) Do write some equivalent C# first, as the editor/compiler can take you a little bit further on the objects/types.


@LexLi, I edited the question as suggested.  Your comment was super helpful, but I can't mark it as the answer.
